# Idiomatic way to handle errors with an early return in Rust

Tags: rust, error-handling, webserver, idioms, actix-web

I currently have the below code to handle the case where I want to handle an error without propagation or continue the function. The use case for this is a web server controller, where I would prefer to manual handle possible errors - which is why the return type is `HttpResponse`.

I want to know if there is a way to do this without this `unwrap` call as in my understanding the compiler should know there is a way to unwrap to a value at this point with no risk of panic.

```rust
    // ...
    
    let result: Result<u8, Error> = func_that_could_error();
    if result.is_err() {
        return HttpResponse::InternalServerError();
    }
    let value: u8 = result.unwrap();
    
    // ...
```

Comment: `let value = result.map_err (|_| HttpResponse::InternalServerError())?;`

Comment: or `let value = match result { Err(_) => return HttpResponse::InternalServerError()), Ok (v) => value, };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can, use `?`:

```
let value = func_that_could_error()?;
```

Optionally mapping it to your error as @Jmb suggests:

```
let value = func_that_could_error()
    .map_err(|_| HttpResponse::InternalServerError())?;
```

Otherwise, use `let else`:

```
let Ok(value) = func_that_could_error() else {
    return HttpResponse::InternalServerError();
};
```

Or, for Rust < 1.65, `match`:

```
let value = match func_that_could_error() {
    Err(_) => return HttpResponse::InternalServerError(),
    Ok(v) => v,
};
```

Comment: There's an extra `if` in your `let-else` example.

Comment: Also while `let-else` is still unstable, [guard](https://crates.io/crates/guard) implements it via a macro (with a few limitations) and is quite reliable, and has worked fine (on stable) for  years. Basically wrap the entire thing (except the trailing `;`) in a `guard!()` and you're done.

Comment: Note: you can only use `?` if your function's return type is either `Result` or `Option`.

Comment: Thanks for the options. The `let-else` is ideal but stuck with stable at the moment. Will be following the RFC for sure.

Comment: @JamesGill Youre welcome. I added `match` alternative.

Comment: Use `ok_or(<err_type>)` for `Option` instead of `Return` ;-)