# Question mark operator replacement when return type is neither Option nor Result

Tags: rust

Rust has a question mark operator than can be used like this:

```rust
fn make_foo() -> Option<Foo> { ... }

fn make_bar() -> Option<Bar> {
    let foo = make_foo()?;
    // ... Many lines of code using `foo` to compute data for `Bar::make` ...
    Some(Bar::make(...))
}
```

But what if I want a function returning `Bar` rather than `Option<Bar>` (thus retuning `Bar::new` instead of `None` when `make_foo()` returns `None`)?

Of course, I could do

```rust
fn make_bar() -> Bar {
    match make_foo() {
        None => { Bar::new() }
        Some(foo) => {
            // ... Many lines of code using `foo` to compute data for `Bar::make` ...
            Bar::make(...)
        }
    }
}
```

but this increases nesting level for the entire function, which I do not like. I would like to have a replacement for the `?` operator.

So I came up with

```rust
fn make_bar() -> Bar {
    let foo = match make_foo() {
        None => { return Bar::new(); }
        Some(v) => v
    };
    // ... Many lines of code using `foo` to compute data for `Bar::make` ...
    Bar::make(...)
}
```

Is this idiomatic Rust? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: Doesn’t look too bad. Though when `let`…`else` lands in stable, there may be a way to make it a little more succinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this idiomatic Rust?

Yes, it looks fine. You can remove the braces:

```
let foo = match make_foo() {
    None => return Bar::new(),
    Some(v) => v
};
```

The best will be [`let-else`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/3137-let-else.md) (unstable):

```
fn make_bar() -> Bar {
    let Some(foo) = match make_foo() else {
        return Bar::new();
    };
    // ... Many lines of code using `foo` to compute data for `Bar::make` ...
    Bar::make(...)
}
```

For a similar one, see [Idiomatic way to handle errors with an early return in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71483198/9305398).

Comment: Note: stable since Rust 1.65

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple ways to do this and I wouldn't necessarily say one is better than the other.  However, let me give you one more option that may be useful if you could be using the `?` operator multiple times in this function.  Having many early `return Bar::new()` will likely get old.  With this approach you can have your cake and eat it too.

`Option` has many utility methods.  You can combine [`.and_then()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) with a final [`.unwrap_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else) in this situation:

```
fn make_bar() -> Bar {
    make_foo()
    .and_then(|foo| {
        // Do stuff with foo
        Some(Bar::make(...))
    })
    .unwrap_or_else(Bar::new)
}
```

This does increase the nesting level, but only once, and has the advantage that you can use `?` inside of the mapping function to cause the outer function to return the default `Bar::new()` value.

(If you implement [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) on `Bar` then you could even use the less-verbose [`.unwrap_or_default()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_default) at the end.)

Comment: I think you'd need to `flatten` or `unwrap` twice in this case. `Option<T>::map` takes a function from `T` to `U` and [returns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) `Option<U>`. So if the mapper returns an `Option<V>` the result would be `Option<Option<V>>`, right?

Comment: @AndreiMatveiakin Yep, I get map confused with and_then a lot. Fixed.