# Result type in Rust and match vs if is_ok

Tags: rust, error-handling

There seem to be two obvious ways to handle a `Result<T, E>` type.

The first is using match, which I believe is used in references such as the Rust Book most frequently.

```
match some_result {
    Ok(value) => {

    },
    Err(error) => {

    },
}
```

However, it is fairly trivial to accomplish the same thing using a combination of `if` `is_ok()` and `unwrap()`.

```
if some_result.is_ok() {
    let some_value = some_result.unwrap();

}
else {

}
```

The match is slightly more elegant in that it doesn't require an additional assignment statement, you already have the type from the name passed to `Ok`.

There is a partner to `unwrap()`, `unwrap_err()` which returns the error, and panics if the result is an `Ok` rather than an `Err`.

This means it is possible to do something like:

```
if some_result.is_ok() {
    let some_value = some_result.unwrap();

}
else {
    let error = some_result.unwrap_err(); // panic if `Ok`

}
```

However, sometimes the `if` statement is easier to use as `match` requires that all branches be compatible in the type they return. (Trivial if `()` is the return type.)

It seems that the most appropriate choice is context dependent.

Is my understanding of the above points raised correct, or have I misunderstood something which means `match` should be used instead of `if`?

Comment: The `if` statement also requires that all branches be compatible in the type they return…

Comment: @Jmb Does `if` always return? I thought its "expression-ness" could be suppressed with `;` ? Maybe I misremember that

Comment: There is [`unwrap_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_err).

Comment: I consider `is_ok()+unwrap()` a Rust antipattern. The fact that that both branches of the if require the same type is a good thing if you use it to initialize something. If you just want to use the value or ignore the error write `if let Ok(x) = some_result { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: `.is_ok()` + `.unwrap()` is flagged as a warning by clippy

Comment: Note that [`is_ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/result.rs.html#539), [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/result.rs.html#1084-1086) and [`unwrap_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/result.rs.html#1179-1181) all use `match` internally, so `is_ok()` + `unwrap()` + `unwrap_err()` is just a way of doing two (or three) `match`es instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

This question is filled with misconceptions.

> There seem to be two obvious ways

There are more than two. For one, you have not considered the `?` operator, which would allow you to elegantly raise errors to the caller.

> sometimes the `if` statement is easier to use as `match` requires that all branches be compatible in the type they return

`if` has *that exact same effect* when used as an expression. Regardless of whether you intend to use `if` or `match`, all conditional expressions must evaluate to the same type.

```rust
let r = Ok(5);
if r.is_ok() {
    r.unwrap()
} else {
   // fails to compile, must return an integer
}
```

So the point made in favor of the second form is moot. As you well indicated, if the intent is to perform side effects without returning something from the `match` or `if` expressions, you can make them return `()` by appending semi-colons in the blocks.

> It seems that the most appropriate choice is context dependent.

The decision is not that blurry at all! There is hardly a good reason to do `if result.is_*()` followed by `unwrap`. Not only is it more verbose and looks uglier, it also has a higher chance of doing redundant checks on the result.

See also:

- [Recoverable errors with Result - The Rust Programming Language, chapter 9](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)
- [Idiomatic way to handle errors with an early return in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71483124/idiomatic-way-to-handle-errors-with-an-early-return-in-rust)
- [What's the difference between using the return statement and omitting the semicolon in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013389/whats-the-difference-between-using-the-return-statement-and-omitting-the-semico)

Comment: And `unwrap()` is generally considered a bad sign. It makes code review harder.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman On that I would just defer to the old-time matter on [whether to panic or not](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html), as `unwrap` has its places.

Comment: Of course there are places when you need to panic, but using `unwrap()` when there is a better alternative makes the reader thinks there can be a panic going on.